# What exactly distinguishes a "streaming" container format for audio/video data?

Tags: streaming, media

Some AV container formats (like MPEG-4 part 14 and Matroska) are supposed to be "streaming-ready" or "streaming file formats", while others like AVI are not. What does that actually mean?

Does that mean that they will tolerate packet loss when sent over an unreliable transport protocol like UDP (without any additional layers like RTP) and enable the clients to resynchronize, or do they still require a reliable transport protocol like TCP?